# CSS grouping incorrectly?

Tags: css, grouping

Why does

```
.right, .left .box_header {
margin: -10px -1.2% 10px -1.2%;
padding: 5px 0.5% 5px 0.5%;
}
```

not do what I would expect it to do (which is)

```
.right .box_header {
margin: -10px -1.2% 10px -1.2%;
padding: 5px 0.5% 5px 0.5%;
}

.left .box_header {
margin: -10px -1.2% 10px -1.2%;
padding: 5px 0.5% 5px 0.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to group several selectors, you have to fully declare them:

```
.right .box_header, .left .box_header  {
margin: -10px -1.2% 10px -1.2%;
padding: 5px 0.5% 5px 0.5%;
}
```

You cannot use `,` to group sub-patterns. See [W3C CSS2 selectors recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)  or [W3C CSS3 selectors recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: blergh. I'm sure I've seen what I've described somewhere else before. thanks.

Comment: Maybe you've seen `.left.box_header, .right{}`, which will result in both `<div class="left box_header"></div>` and `<div class="right box_header"></div>` to behave the same. But I wouldn't recommend this, since `<div class="right"></div>` will get styled too.

Answer (score 2):

Its because in your first code, you are declaring TWO DIFFERENT selections.

i) class selector (.right) 
**It styles ANY element with class 'right' attached.**

ii) ancestor descendant selector(.left .box_header)
It styles any element of class 'box_header' that MUST BE descendant of element of class 'left' attached.

While in your second code you explicitly declaring styles for

i) ancestor descendant selector(.right .box_header)
**It styles any element of class 'box_header' that MUST BE descendant of element of class 'right' attached.**

And to declare both styles correctly you can use following code

```
.right .box_header, .left .box_header  {
/* Styles here*/
}
```

ii) ancestor descendant selector(.left .box_header)ii)
It styles any element of class 'box_header' that MUST BE descendant of element of class 'right' attached.

That's why both codes have different effect.